# telnet to godaddy email server on ubuntu desktop

Tags: imap, telnet

I'm on my home computer (ubuntu desktop). I am reading the documentations for the IMAP protocol. And I want to connect to my email host at imap.secureserver.net on port 993. Then I want to issue a few IMAP commands like logging in:

```
a01 login myuser mypassword
RESPONSE: a01 OK User logged in
```

But when I run telnet on terminal, I get a message "Connection closed by foreign host":

```
$ telnet imap.secureserver.net 993
Trying 72.167.218.187...
Connected to imap.secureserver.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
a01 myuser@mysite.com password
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Any idea why it closes connection rather than giving me an ok response?

Comment: I don't see this as anything to with Ubuntu distribution or any of its components but to check with the respective hosting provider. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

port 993 is IMAP over SSL, apparently godaddy does not accept this via telnet. The solution is to use the default IMAP port 143, and that works:

```
telnet imap.secureserver.net 143
Trying 173.201.193.71...
Connected to imap.where.secureserver.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT STARTTLS ID CHILDREN NAMESPACE IDLE] Courier-IMAP ready. Copyright 1998-2004 Double Precision, Inc.  See COPYING for distribution information.
```

And then you can log in:

```
a01 login myemail mypassword
a01 OK LOGIN Full IMAP support is enabled
```